# Test cases are failed. Java-loop-multiplication-table

Tags: java, loops, testcase

When a number is given between 2 to 20. The program should print multiplication table of the number up to 10. There is no compliation error but when uploading to hackerrank it says test cases are failed. Why is that?

*Example:*

```
Input= 2
output:
2*1=2
2*2=4
.
.
.
2*10=20
```

*Code:*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
int result;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        if(N>=2 || N<=20){
            for(int x=1;x<=10;x++){
                System.out.println("N*x=result");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Question: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yJucc6sQiRjZCCC09fAy7CfFhOI9X35m

Comment: `System.out.println("N*x=result");` - your program will just print `"N*x=result"` ten times...

Comment: what is the question exactly? where are those test cases?

Comment: Have you tested it? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    System.out.println("N*x=result");
}
```

Because the code above just prints `N*x=result` ten times.  You need to actually print the variables:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
    System.out.println(N + "*" + x + "=" + (N * x));
}
```

**Note**: Your condition is also incorrect:

```
if(N>=2 || N<=20)
```

should be

```
if (N >= 2 && N <= 20)
```

Comment: Hi there! thank you for replying me. I put the link of the question. Can you check. I modified according to you. But it didn't work. Thank You

Comment: "But it didn't work." - You'll need to provide some explanation of how it *didn't work*.  It works fine on my end!